# "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'" when trying to apply lambda to create new column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I aim at adding a new column in a Pandas DataFrame, but I am facing an weird error.

The new column is expected to be a transformation from an existing column, that can be done doing a lookup in a dictionary/hashmap.

```
# Loading data
df = sqlContext.read.format(...).load(train_df_path)

# Instanciating the map
some_map = {
    'a': 0, 
    'b': 1,
    'c': 1,
}

# Creating a new column using the map
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: some_map(row.some_column_name), axis=1)
```

Which leads to the following error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-aeee412b10bf> in <module>()
     25 df= train_df
     26 
---> 27 df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: some_map(row.some_column_name), axis=1)

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    962         if name not in self.columns:
    963             raise AttributeError(
--> 964                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
    965         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
    966         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Other potentially useful info:
 * I am using Spark and Python 2.

Comment: That's not a pandas DataFrame I think. The error is raised by a Spark DataFrame?

Comment: Have you in your script somewhere defined a variable named `apply`?

Comment: @user2285236 That might be why I am confused. Do you know how to apply a lambda in that case with spark?

Comment: @Harv Ipan No I don't have a variable named apply. My aim is to run a lambda in order to create a new column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you are using is for a `pandas` DataFrame. To achieve this for a `spark` DataFrame, you should use the `withColumn()` method. This works great for a wide range of well defined [DataFrame functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions), but it's a little more complicated for user defined mapping functions.

#### General Case

In order to define a `udf`, you need to specify the output data type. For instance, if you wanted to apply a function `my_func` that returned a `string`, you could create a `udf` as follows:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
my_udf = f.udf(my_func, StringType())
```

Then you can use `my_udf` to create a new column like:

```python
df = df.withColumn('new_column', my_udf(f.col("some_column_name")))
```

Another option is to use `select`:

```python
df = df.select("*", my_udf(f.col("some_column_name")).alias("new_column"))
```

---

#### Specific Problem

**Using a `udf`**

In your specific case, you want to use a dictionary to translate the values of your DataFrame.

Here is a way to define a `udf` for this purpose:

```python
some_map_udf = f.udf(lambda x: some_map.get(x, None), IntegerType())
```

Notice that I used `dict.get()` because you want your `udf` to be robust to bad inputs.

```python
df = df.withColumn('new_column', some_map_udf(f.col("some_column_name")))
```

**Using DataFrame functions**

Sometimes using a `udf` is unavoidable, but whenever possible, using DataFrame functions is usually preferred.

Here is one option to do the same thing without using the `udf`.

The trick is to iterate over the items in `some_map` to create a list of [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) functions.

```python
some_map_func = [f.when(f.col("some_column_name") == k, v) for k, v in some_map.items()]
print(some_map_func)
#[Column<CASE WHEN (some_column_name = a) THEN 0 END>,
# Column<CASE WHEN (some_column_name = c) THEN 1 END>,
# Column<CASE WHEN (some_column_name = b) THEN 1 END>]
```

Now you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) inside of a select:

```python
df = df.select("*", f.coalesce(*some_map_func).alias("some_column_name"))
```

This works because `when()` returns `null` by default if the condition is not met, and `coalesce()` will pick the first non-null value it encounters. Since the keys of the map are unique, at most one column will be non-null.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spark dataframe, not a pandas dataframe. To add new column to the spark dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
df = df.withColumn('new_column', F.udf(some_map.get, IntegerType())(some_column_name))
df.show()
```