# PySpark Dynamic When Statement

Tags: python-2.7, loops, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of strings I am using to create column names. This list is dynamic and may change over time. Depending on the value of the string the column name changes. An example of the code I currently have is below:

```
df = df.withColumn("newCol", \
    F.when(df.pet == "dog", df.dog_Column) \
    .otherwise(F.when(df.pet == "cat", df.cat_Column) \
    .otherwise(None))))
```

I want to return the column that is a derivation of the name in the list. I would like to do something like this instead:

```
dfvalues = ["dog", "cat", "parrot", "goldfish"]

df = df.withColumn("newCol", F.when(df.pet == dfvalues[0], \
     F.col(dfvalues[0] + "_Column"))
```

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to make a looping condition in Pyspark.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way could be to use a list comprehension in conjuction with a `coalesce`, very similiar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686923/5858851).

```python
mycols = [F.when(F.col("pet") == p, F.col(p + "_Column")) for p in dfvalues]
df = df.select("*", F.coalesce(*mycols).alias("newCol"))
```

This works because `when()` will return `None` if the is no `otherwise()`, and `coalesce()` will pick the first non-null column.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and found this site [link](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/performing-operations-on-multiple-columns-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-36e97896c378).You can use python reduce to looping for clean solution.

```
from functools import reduce

def update_col(df1, val):
    return df.withColumn('newCol', 
               F.when(F.col('pet') == val, F.col(val+'_column')) \
                .otherwise(F.col('newCol')))

# add empty column
df1 = df.withColumn('newCol', F.lit(0))

reduce(update_col, dfvalues, df1).show()
```

that yields:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
dfvalues = ["dog", "cat"]
df = df.withColumn("newCol", F.when(df.pet == dfvalues[0], F.col(dfvalues[0] + "_Column")))

df.show()

+----------+----------+---+------+
|cat_column|dog_column|pet|newCol|
+----------+----------+---+------+
|      cat1|      dog1|dog|  dog1|
|      cat2|      dog2|cat|  cat2|
+----------+----------+---+------+
```